# Netty Server, at the same time need to be a client

Tags: networking, netty

I want to create a server to let clients connect to, so from this point, it's a server only. But, at the same time, this server - let's call it "Server A" - it need to connect to another server (I'll call it "Server B") to report its own information, not as a proxy that route data from client to "Server B", only report it's information like "I'm still online".

So, many clients will connect to "Server A", and "Server A" will connect to "Server B" as a client. How can I do this by using Netty?

I read netty's proxy example, but I think the proxy server is create a client when it receive a client's connection temporary. But I need a dedicate client role for this purpose on "Server A", not like that. Help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bootstrap your client to Server B in the `channelActive` or any other method of your Server A handler. Then once the client bootstrap is successful you can send any message to your Server B using the client.

An example is here: 
https://github.com/normanmaurer/netty-in-action/blob/2.0-SNAPSHOT/chapter8/src/main/java/nia/chapter8/BootstrapSharingEventLoopGroup.java

Instead of setting a `childHandler` for your server, you can set the `handler` for the `ServerChannel`. Then its methods would be called only once for the server and not for each client connection.

Comment: If I bootstrap a client in the channel active, that means when Server A receives a client connection, that bootstrap code runs. If the second client of Server A links, the bootstrap code runs again? If that is true when clients connect to Server A, I will get more and more client instance (to link to Server B), that isn't what I want. Correct me if I am wrong, please.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Use handler instead of childHandler for your purpose

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works. Thank you. Will accept your answer after hours.